# Is there any way to force load a module when it is opened through FSI?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

If I compile the following module into a dll

```
namespace MyNs
module SomeModule =
    do printfn "module loading"
    let x = 23
```

then reference the dll in FSI and execute the command `open MyNs.SomeModule` "module loading" does not print immediately. It only prints when I access `x` which causes all the top level let and do bindings to execute (normal behavior I know in the .NET world). Is there any way, perhaps via an attribute on the module, I can indicate that module should load immediately upon opening in FSI?

Comment: Have you tried `module SomeModule = MyNS.SomeModule` instead of `open MyNS.SomeModule`? I wonder if that would be any different. FWIW, this works as you expect using 'Send To Interactive' from VS.

Comment: @Daniel - just tried it, `module SomeModule = MyNS.SomeModule` doesn't do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening a module never does anything at runtime. It just puts all the symbols in the opened namespace in scope for unqualified access below the open statement.

Section 12.5 of the [language spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597616) is what you want to read - this details when the static initialization of a module will run.

Given that, the only time when this initialization is run automatically, as far as I know, is for last module in an exe.

I.e. I don't think there is a direct way to accomplish what you want.

If you have reflective access to the module:

```
ModuleType.TypeInitializer.Invoke(null, null)
```

will invoke the static initialization.

Comment: When I do this, it executes the do block twice!  Any idea how to avoid that?

Comment: Debug into it and see from where both are called, I guess. I didn't think that's possible, but have not looked into it much.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the AutoOpen attribute to the module

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module SomeModule =
  do printfn "module loading"
  let x = 23
```

However this will only print the module loading message when you reference x.

Comment: Thanks @Nick R, but I am specifically looking for a way to "auto load" a module upon opening (whether it be opened explicitly or via AutoOpen) *without* needing to force the loading through referencing `x` in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found the solution to your problem but in my case I wanted to start an agent when my website was starting and it was indeed starting twice like you mentioned.

What I did was set a method `let start() =` inside the module and invoke the method using a `static do xxx.start()` from my main `Site` type.

Found that by reading the language spec Kurt linked.